# EF Core, way to enforce pair foreign keys as unique

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, relationship

I have a many to many `UsersContacts` relationship table represented by the EF entity `UserContact`. The relationship is a symmetrical many to many linking pairs of users from a `Users` table.

**My goal:** on each insert/search, having a unique combination of pairs of users. Regardless of the order of the columns (IdUserA, IdUserB) or (IdUserB, IdUserA), doesn't matter.

i.e:

`UsersContacts`:

| Id | IdUserA | IdUserB | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Ok |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | Ok |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | Ok |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | Ok |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | Duplicate |
| 6 | 14 | 2 | Ok |
| 7 | 2 | 1 | Duplicate |
| 8 | 2 | 2 | Ok |

What I have set so far is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserContact>()
            .HasIndex(uc => new { uc.IdUserA, uc.IdUserB})
            .IsUnique();
```

But I presume that this is mono-directional only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to prevent there being a row with `IdUserA: 1, IdUserB: 5` as well as `IdUserA: 5, IdUserB: 1`?

Comment: You could ensure in application logic that the lowest Id is always `IdUserA`. That can even be enforced by a check constraint in the database table.

Comment: @Xedni Yes exactly

Comment: @GertArnold Negative for enforcing any order, the id's are Guid's. I've put integers in the question for simplicity. Sorry for misleading

Comment: @anaitslimane - GUIDs are comparable and as such can be enforced via a check constraint as was suggested above.

Answer (score 2):

`Guid`'s/`uniqueidentifier` are comparable both on SQL Server and .NET side.

> The only operations that are allowed against a `uniqueidentifier` value are comparisons (=, <>, <, >, <=, >=) and checking for NULL (IS NULL and IS NOT NULL)

You can try maintaining the join table in a way that `IdUserA` is greater or equal (or less or equal) than `IdUserB`. For example using check constraint. Something along these lines:

```cs
modelBuilder
    .Entity<UserContact>()
    .ToTable(uc => uc.HasCheckConstraint("CK_IdUserA_GE_IdUserB", "IdUserA >= IdUserB"))
    .HasIndex(uc => new { uc.IdUserA, uc.IdUserB});
```

And then maintain this property in the code on the insert. Note that according to the [Comparing GUID and uniqueidentifier values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/compare-guid-uniqueidentifier-values?view=sql-server-ver16#comparing-guid-values) doc you should use [`SqlGuid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqlguid?view=net-8.0) to perform comparisons in the code:

> `SqlGuid` implements `CompareTo` using SQL Server behavior, in the last six bytes of a value are most significant. `Guid` evaluates all 16 bytes.

If you don't mind introducing computed columns you can make this approach more SQL native - create a computed column (something like `CalculatedId AS IIF(IdUserA > IdUserB, IdUserA, IdUserB) + '-' + IIF(IdUserA > IdUserB, IdUserB, IdUserA)`) and set unique index on it.

Comment: Thank you for the effort @Guru Stron. This could be indeed a way, among others to achieving the goal.

Comment: I was hoping for a more EF'ish or even SQL'ish native way of having a  pair key constraint

Comment: @anaitslimane added description for more SQL native way - create a computed column and index on it or directly index on such computation.

Comment: Yes, could be something like that too. I was thinking myself of a condition on the inserts requests (IF NOT EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM .. )

Comment: I really am surprised that strict unicity on tuplets FK's is not a thing. I mean, I believe that this technical/business requirement has sprung in thousands of minds before me, I am sure

Comment: @anaitslimane I would argue that this comes from the SQL standard and how indexes are build. I'm pretty much sure that there is no specific syntax in the ANSI SQL for such thing and designing and implementing such feature arguably has to low cost/value ratio.

Comment: @anaitslimane IMO a check constraint is just as SQL-ish as a unique constraint (and less involving) but of course it's not that "SQL-ish" is well-defined :)

Comment: I thank you all for your input. I don't believe that comparing ID's is a suitable solution for me, since it introduces semantics which say nothing about (I want a unique pair of Id's, regardless of order). I will go with a more clear path semantically: I will create a function which I'll set as a check constraint: SELECT 1 FROM USERSCONTACTS uc WHERE (uc.IdUserA = idUserA and uc.IdUserB = idUserB) or (uc.IdUserB = idUserA and uc.IdUserA = idUserB). I am aware that it might be less efficient performance wise, but it's not an issue for me, since the inserts will be rather rare than too many.

Comment: Function for check constraints doesn't work for updates if I remember correctly. Don't do this

Comment: @siggemannen I did a quick search and stumbled upon those: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50745313/check-constraint-that-calls-function-does-not-work-on-update and https://sqlblog.karaszi.com/be-careful-with-constraints-calling-udfs. But I don't see anything related to my case, since, for me, a contact between users exists (on insert) or does not exist (on delete), I will never do any update on any rows. the only other column (apart from the two user's id's) is a DateTimeCreated. Did I miss something?

Comment: @siggemannen This only relates to check constraints calling a UDF (which is bad practice anyway). It would be a disaster if check constraints structurally didn't work for updates.

Comment: @GertArnold yeah, OP was writing his plan was to use a check constraints with a function. I think it's a bad idea all around :D